# C++ using new to create unique object pointers within a loop

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, unique, operator-keyword

I'm attempting to systematically instantiate Nodes holding objects of type Student in a doubly linked list. My doubly linked list works fine when I manually create nodes and add them to the list, but when I instantiate Nodes in a loop, the pointers are overridden.

For the sake of this code, I need to instantiate a certain number of Nodes according to input from a text file, so I must use a loop.

```
DoublyLinkedList<Student> dlist;

for(int j = 0; j<numOfStudents;j++)
{
    getline(myfile,line);
    Student student1 =  Student(toInt(line));     //toInt() converts string to Int
    Node<Student> node1 = Node<Student> (student1);
    dlist.add(&node1);
}
```

The problem I'm having though, is that if a text file has the following parameters for students.

6

11

9

Then the doubly linked lists will simply be filled with 3 instances of the same Student Object that has '9' as a parameter.

Researching the problem, I've found that using the new operator would provide each object a unique pointer, as long as I delete it afterwards to prevent memory leakage. But, in attempting to implement it by adding new in front of Node, i'm receiving the error that there is

no viable conversion from 'Node *' to
      'Node'

I would very much appreciate any insight into the issue or a push in the right direction.

Comment: `Node<Student> *node1 = new Node<Student> (student1);
    dlist.add(node1);` Try changing the type of node1.

Comment: Your code is not quite "cosher" C++ in that loop: it is creating temporary objects that get assigned to another object with an assignment. This looks more like Java or C# (which may be your background?) If you show more of your code it may help in explaining the results you are getting.

Comment: Please provide [a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can actually help you instead of guessing what the problem is. I don't see any dynamic allocation in the code you've provide.

Comment: The object `node1` is *destroyed* at the `}`. Which means that you now have an invalid pointer in your linked list. After reading three students you now have three invalid pointers in your linked list. Which may or may not appear to contain the same value 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j<numOfStudents;j++)
{
    getline(myfile,line);
    Student student1 =  Student(toInt(line));     //toInt() converts string to Int
    Node<Student> node1 = Node<Student> (student1);
   dlist.add(&node1);
```

}

We have two issue here.

First, student1 and node1 only have scope withing your loop. That means that when the loop exits the data in your list is no longer valid. It is possible that the data in student1 is copied in the construction of node1 making the fact that student1 only scope in the loop irreverent, but node1 is a definitely problem.

Second, you add a pointer to node1 to your list numOfStudents times.

One solution involves allocating memory for your "Nodes"

```
for(int j = 0; j<numOfStudents;j++)
{
    getline(myfile,line);
    Student student1 =  Student(toInt(line));     //toInt() converts string to Int
   // Create a new node to add to the list 
   Node<Student> *node1 = new Node<Student> (student1);

   // Add the node to the list
   dlist.add(node1);
}
```

What is important to remember here is that when you remove elements from the list they must be freed when you are done with them.

```
delete <pointer to allocated node>
```